# When $A=BC$ where $B$ is a singular, can we find an explicit form of $C$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, generalized-inverse

$A=BC$, where $B$ is a singular and every matrix is a $n\times n$ matrix.
Can we find an explicit form of $C$?

If $B$ is non-singular, $C=B^{-1}A$ is obvious. But I am not sure how to find out the form of $C$ when $B$ is singular. It can be $B^-A=B^-BC$, where $B^-$ is a generalized inverse of $B$ However, it doesn't result in an explicit form of $C$.

Thank you for all of your comments in advance.

Comment: $0=0C$ for all $C$, so you can't hope for something like this

Comment: If $B$ is singular, this equation doesn't have an unique solution for $C$. It may have no solution (example: $B$ is the zero matrix, $A$ is nonzero), or it may have infinitely many solutions (example: both $A$ and $B$ are the zero matrix).

Comment: There are many ways that the image of $C$ can be contained in the kernel (nullspace) of $B$, since $B$ is singular.  This gives lots of solutions to the equation $0 = BC$.

Comment: I think this question is salvageable, despite the examples in comments above. Singular is equivalent to having a characteristic polynomial with a root at zero; perhaps we can determine some information about $C$ if we have a bound on the multiplicity of this root?

Comment: Thank you for all of quick and helpful answers!

Answer (score 1):

There does not always (for an arbitrary $A$) exist such a matrix $C$ and when it does, it's **never** unique. To see this simply, you have to realize that $$BC=A$$ is $n$ separate equations: one for each column of $A$. If we denote the columns of $A$ by $a_i$ and the unknown columns of $C$ by $c_i$, then the $n$ equations are $$Bc_1=a_1$$ $$Bc_2=a_2$$ $$\cdots$$ $$Bc_n=a_n.$$
Each one of these equations only has a solution if $a_n$ is in the column space of $B$, which presumably is the case if $A$ was obtained as the product $BC$ However, then each equation has a solution of the form $$c_i=p_i+N_B,$$ where $p_i$ is a particular solution and $N_B$ is the null space of the matrix $B$.